# Kotlin constrain generic method's type parameter to be a supertype of class's type parameter

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm trying to get a class similar to this (contrived) example to compile:

```kotlin
class Foo<T> {
    
    val value: T
    val condition: Boolean
    
    fun <R> transform(func: () -> R): R {
        return if (condition) {
            func()
        } else {
            // Type mismatch: required: R, found: T
            value
        }
    }
    
}
```

The `transform` method can return either `value` or the result of `func()`, so `T` should be assignable to `R`. Is there a way to express this in Kotlin?

I tried using `where T : R`, but the compiler doesn't understand that `T` should refer to the class's `T`. An extension function could work, but I want to avoid that because it complicates Java interoperability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this , it works. You need to pass two type params while initializing.

```
class Foo<T:R,R> constructor(val value: T,val condition: Boolean) {
    fun transform(func: () -> R): R {
        return if (condition) {
            func()
        } else {
            value
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

[image]

```
  var s = Foo<String,CharSequence>("12",false).transform {
        "as"
    }
```

You pass "12" as string . Transform return "as" value as CharSequence .

***Update:***
As far as I know, only using extension function might be solve your requirement.

Here is the extension function solution.

```
class Foo<T> constructor(val value: T,val condition: Boolean){}
fun <T:R,R> Foo<T>.transform(func: () -> R):R{
    return if (condition) {
        func()
    } else {
        value
    }
}
```

Example of using extension function solution.

```
fun main() {
    var s1 = Foo(setOf("Hello"),false).transform<Set<String>,Iterable<String>> {
        setOf("World")
    }
    var s2 = Foo(listOf("Hello"),false).transform<List<String>,Iterable<String>> {
        listOf("World")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but it restricts a given instance of `Foo` to a single type of transformation. I want to use `transform` in various (not known upfront) circumstances, similar to `Iterable.map`.

Comment: Kotlin does not support inferring member type param from class type param. I have updated the answer with simple extension function solution. –

Answer (score 0):

You just use the type parameter from the class directly. Your method doesn't need to introduce another type parameter:

```
class Foo<T> {
    val value: T
    val condition: Boolean

    fun transform(func: () -> T): T {
        return if (condition) {
            func()
        } else {
            value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This restricts `func` to return (subtypes of) `T`, I want it to be able to return "anything" `value` is compatible with (including supertypes of `T`).

Comment: But that is just not type safe. You would have to return `Any`.

Comment: Actually, what do you mean by `anything value is compatible with`? That is just `T` and the subclasses of it if I interpret it correctly.

Comment: It would be type-safe if I could express this constraint to the compiler.

To give an example: `bestFriend: Animal = (Foo<Cow>).transform(::findBestFriend)`.
The best friend of my `Cow` doesn't have to be another cow (could be a [chicken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vii7Tkejrfg)), but we know it's definitely some kind of `Animal`. The return type of `findBestFriend` should therefore be `Animal`, which `Cow` is compatible with, so this is perfectly type-safe in this context.

Comment: So if you put `::findFavoriteCupOfTea` it would give `Any`?

Comment: My usage of "compatible with" in my earlier comment is a bit ambiguous now that I read it again, for clarity: anything `value` would be _assignable to_. As in if `value` is a `Cow` it's assignable to (thus compatible with) `Animal`.

Comment: `::findFavoriteCupOfTea` would fail compilation, because `Tea` (`R`) is not a supertype of `Cow` (`T`), at least that's the constraint I'm trying to express.